# no puedo obtener valor de seleccion laravel

Tags: laravel, formularios, select

ocupe un pakage de [laravel-adminpanel](https://github.com/appzcoder/laravel-admin) para realizar el tema de roles usuarios y permisos.

Para poder agregar un usuario editarlo y etc, tengo que agregar otras cosas (teléfono, dirección,etc), ya que a la tabla users de laravel le agregue mas columnas.

como es un package ya me tenia las paginas casi armadas entonces solo agrego "inputs" el problema es que no puedo obtener el id de un select que tengo, les adjuntare el código.

FORM

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('sex') ? ' has-error' : ''}}">
    {!! Form::label('sex', 'Sexo: ', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::select('sexo[]', $sexo, isset($sexo_nombre) ? $sexo_nombre : [], ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
    public function create()
    {
        $roles = Role::select('id', 'name', 'label')->get();
        $roles = $roles->pluck('label', 'name');
        $sexo1 =  Sexo::select('idsexo','nombre')->get();
        $sexo = $sexo1->pluck('nombre');


        return view('admin.users.create', compact('roles','sexo'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(
            $request,
            [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|string|max:255|email|unique:users',
                'apellido' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'edad' => 'required|integer',
                'telefono' => 'required|integer',
                'estatura' => 'required|integer',
                'peso' => 'required|integer',
                'password' => 'required',
                'roles' => 'required'
            ]
        );

        $data = $request->except('password');
        $data['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user = User::create($data);

        foreach ($request->roles as $role) {
            $user->assignRole($role);
        }

        return redirect('admin/users')->with('flash_message', 'User added!');
    }
```

> SE QUE YA NO SE OCUPA EL FORMATO "FORM::ETC" PERO QUERIA DEJARLO ASI
>   PARA NO MODIFICAR EL CODIGO ORIGINAL

**

> ADJUNTO IMAGEN DEL NUEVO ERROR.

**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por tomar tu tiempo y responder mi pregunta estimado, efectivamente creo que me captura el id del sexo, pero ahora me sucede un nuevo error el cual es "Array to string conversion" maracandome esta linea de codigo que se encuentra en mi controller, incluso esta en la publicación "$user = User::create($data);" adjuntare imagen del error editando la pregunta, de nuevo, gracias por responder

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ.

Comment: me da el mismo error :c, le borre lo que me mencionaste @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ya la edite y agregue el código actual que tengo, gracias

Comment: excelente estimado! @porloscerrosΨ agregue su respuesta como...respuesta jeje, para poder darle el ok!! me sirvio muchas gracias!

Comment: no tu fuiste el que me ayudo así te dan puntos, es tu ayuda! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El nombre del select va sin corchetes: `sexo` y no `sexo[]`. De otra forma PHP lo tomará como un array de valores.

Y el valor por defecto sería `null` y no un array vacío `isset($sexo_nombre) ? $sexo_nombre : null` en vez de `isset($sexo_nombre) ? $sexo_nombre : []`.

```
{!! Form::select('sexo', $sexo, isset($sexo_nombre) ? $sexo_nombre : null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

---

*Referencias:*
Esto es lo que estabas haciendo y te generaba el error:
PHP [¿Cómo creo arrays en un  de HTML?](https://www.php.net/manual/es/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) 
PHP [¿Cómo obtengo todos los resultados de una etiqueta de selección múltiple en HTML?](https://www.php.net/manual/es/faq.html.php#faq.html.select-multiple)

La de la librería que usas:
Laravel Collective [Drop-Down Lists](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#drop-down-lists)

Answer (score 0):

El error tiene que ver con el como ingresas los datos para crear el usuario, primero debes asegurarte que dentro de tu modelo `User` tengas la variable `$fillable` con los datos que vas a ingresar de la siguiente forma:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'apellido','email', 'edad','telefono', 'estatura','peso', 'password', 'roles'
];
```

Y al momento de usar el método create pasas los valores de la siguiente manera

```
$user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'apellido' => $data['lastname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'edad' => $data['phone'],
        'telefono' => $data['phone'],
        'peso' => $data['address'],
        'password' => $data['address'],
        'roles' => $data['address'],
      ]);
```